# Different results when using mockito matchers anyList() and any(List.class)

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have found that there are different results when using mockito matchers anyList() and any(List.class). I can not unterstand this, however, since both should actually return the same result. Maybe someone can enlighten me.

I use the matcher to test a controller. My controller binds an attribute to the model called myList. I want to verify that the model attribute is actually a list.

```
model.addAttribute("myList", Arrays.asList("test"));
```

any(List.class) performs a correct test:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(model().attribute("myList", any(List.class)));
```

But anyList() returns that [] was expected and causes a test failure:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(model().attribute("myList", anyList()));
```

I need anyListOf(String.class) to verify that the list contains strings, but I can not use it because of this behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. Please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`ModelResultMatchers.attribute()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), which checks that the model attribute named "myList" is equal to the second argument, i.e. is equal to the value returned by `any(List.class)` or `anyList()`.

Note that this method doesn't expect a Mockito matcher at all. It isn't even related to Mockito at all. It just expects a value, and checks that the model attribute is equal to this value.

`anyList()` returns a new empty ArrayList. `any(List.class)` returns null. So your first test succeeds because your controller happens to store null in this model attribute, and your second test fails because null is not equal to an empty ArrayList.

TL;DR: you shouldn't use Mockito matchers here. That makes no sense.

Comment: Not really. There is also: attribute (String name, org.hamcrest.Matcher <T> matcher). This method expect a matcher. And any(List.class) does not return null. The second test also does not fails because null is not equal to an empty List. The trace is:

java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'myList'
Expected: is <[]>
     but: was <[String@7b886bd3]>

Comment: You said you're using Mockito matchers. Here's the javadoc of the any() mockito matcher: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any(java.lang.Class). As you see, it doesn't return an org.hamcrest.Matcher <T>. It returns T, so, in this case a List, and the javadoc clearly says that the return value is null. So, my guess is that, in this case, you didn't use a mockito matcher, but a Hamcrest Matcher, which is correct.

Comment: But anyList() (https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyList()), as you see, does not return a Matcher, but a List. And as you see, the returned value is an empty list. Which confirms the error message: you told Spring to expect an empty list ([]), and you passed a non empty list ([String@7b886bd3])